# .append() not injecting content correctly in jQuery

Tags: jquery

This code:

```
$("div.content form#registration").append('<div class="submit-area">');
    $("div.content form#registration").append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">');
    $("div.content form#registration").append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Next »">');
$("div.content form#registration").append('</div');
```

produces this:

```
<div class="submit-area"></div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Next »">
```

instead of:

```
<div class="submit-area">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Next »">
</div>
```

How to achieve the later with input elements inside of submit-area class?

Comment: You want to append the 2 inputs to the submit area div and then append that div to the registration

Comment: Indenting your code does not tell your append to go inside the previously appended div.  You must append your inputs to $("div.submit-area")

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('<div class="submit-area">')
    .append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">')
    .append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Next »">')
    .appendTo("div.content form#registration")
```

You basically create the `div` element, add the input elements, and then append it to `div.content form#registration` (which can probably be written as `#registration` BTW).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pRD55/

Answer (score 0):

You are appending and appending to the same elements. You can go about this two ways:

```
$("div.content form#registration").append('<div class="submit-area">\
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">\
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Next »">\
</div');
```

The first one is to append just one big chunk of html.

```
$("div.content form#registration").append('<div class="submit-area">');
$("div.content form#registration .submit-area").append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">');
$("div.content form#registration .submit-area").append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Next »">');
```

The second one appends to the first appended box and does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is perfectly okay. You're trying to append multiple elements into a single one. Therefore they all get appended one after another (instead of inside each other).

Try to change it to this:

```
$("div.content").append('<div class="submit-area"></div>');
$("div.submit-area").append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">');
$("div.submit-area").append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Next »">');
```

Also notice, that I have removed the `append` for the additional `</div` because *1)* it lacks a `>`, and *2)* it's unnecessary, as the div will already be closed once the second append happens.

Comment: Still produce the same markup as his original code though.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this syntax. You must understand that `.append()` doesn't simply add line in the HTML but insert elements inside others.

```
var myNewDiv = $('<div class="submit-area">');
myNewDiv .append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">');
myNewDiv .append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Next »">');
$("div.content form#registration").append(myNewDiv);
```

Comment: `$("div.content form#registration").append(myNewDiv);` should be the last line to avoid redrawing the document more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues.

1) You aren't closing the div at the end "

2) This really isn't an efficient method of doing it. Put all the HTML into a variable and append all at once. JQuery will only have to edit the DOM once, not query and edit it four times.

```
var html = '<div class="submit-area"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Next »"></div>';

$("div.content form#registration").append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
var my_html = '<div class="submit-area">';
my_html    += '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">';
my_html    += '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next" value="Next »">';
my_html    += '</div>';

$(my_html).appendTo("div.content form#registration");
```

ps. you was missing  ">" end of your last div tag..

Comment: `.=` will generate a `SyntaxError`, the right way to append to strings in javascript is via `+=` see http://jsfiddle.net/3ZsL9/

Answer (score 0):

When you append a div jquery will automatically close it for you and `.append('</div');` will be ignored, you're missing a `>` there by the way.

The way to produce the code you want would be to do this

```
$("<div class='submit-area'>")
    .append(
        $('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">'),
        $('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="previoyus" value="« Previous">')
    )
.appendTo("#registration");
```

Note I removed the `div.content` from the selector as it is not necessary as you are targeting the form via `id`

Also note `append` can take multiple elements as arguments so it it not necessary to call it twice.

http://jsfiddle.net/67aYC/1/